# Use ApolloClient in Gatsby with localhost / local IP uri

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to use `ApolloClient` with a local IP as `uri`, but when I set it, it automatically changes it from `http` to `https` and, of course, it doesn't work locally.

I've tried 2 way of configuring `Gatsby` to use `ApolloClient`.

1. The first way is in `gatsby-browser` like so:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import 'core-js/modules/es6.set';
    import 'core-js/modules/es6.map';
    import 'raf/polyfill';
    import Apollo from 'providers/Apollo';

    export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => <Apollo>{element}</Apollo>;
```

And, the `ApolloClient` config:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { ApolloProvider, ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

    export default ({ children }) => {
      const client = new ApolloClient({
        uri: 'http://192.162.1.112:4000/graphql',
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        request: async operation => {
          ...
        },
        fetchOptions: {
          mode: 'no-cors',
        },
      });

      return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>;
    };
```

2. The second way is using the plugin `gatsby-plugin-apollo` in `gatsby-config` like so

```
    {
       resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-apollo',
       options: {
         uri: 'http://192.168.1.112:4000/graphql'
       }
    }
```

Notice both `uri` have `http`.
Also, it is either one or the other, not both. (Although I've tried with both and it the same result).

This is what I get trying to do a `gql` query in the network tab:

[image]

It is enforcing `https` and I can't test locally. How do can I make request to `http` using `Gatsby` and `ApolloClient`?

By the way, I set `ApolloClient` just like this in another project that doesn't use `Gatsby` (obviously not using the gatsby plugin either) and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few confusing things in the way you are using apollo client. 
There is no point in explaining something that has already been done.

You might want to check out this talk and demo by **Jason Lengstorf**. Here he explained how one can get started with gatsby + apollo client.

[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNUg1jpj9T0&feature=youtu.be&t=975)

[gatsby-with-apollo](https://github.com/jlengstorf/gatsby-with-apollo)